# CommandBar onaction - trying to run a sub stored in the form code

Tags: excel, vba

I can create a right-click pop-up menu on my form. I would like to run a sub when the menu item is selected by setting the onaction to the name of my subroutine.

This works only if the subroutine is in a module rather than the form code.

Is there any way to get it to work with subroutines stored in the form code?

Comment: Try making the subrutine `Public` and call it using `Me.SubName`. If it does not work, try using `formName.SubName`...

Answer (score 0):

*(In the following, I assume that your form name is `UserForm1` and the Sub is named `TestSub`)*.

As long as your Sub is `Public`, you can call it with `UserForm1.TestSub`.

However, that's a slippery path, and it's not easy to understand. A form is a class, and you will need an instance of this class before you can call any method of it - with other words an object needs to be created first.

Now there's a feature in VBA that you can create an userform object implicitly when using its (class) name: `UserForm1.Show` will create an object of type `UserForm1` on the fly and show it (this is called the "default instance"). When you call `UserForm1.TestSub` and this default instance is already created (you used the `USerForm1.Show`-command), it will call the Sub of this instance. However, if the instance is *not* yet created, it will create this and, without showing the form, call `TestSub`.

But what happens if you don't want to use the default instance (**and there are good reasons for that**)? Consider the following code (lives in a regular module). It will create 2 instances of the form and show both non-modal:

```
Option Explicit
Dim f1 As UserForm1, f2 As UserForm1

Sub createForms()
    Set f1 = New UserForm1
    f1.Label1.Caption "I am Form f1"
    f1.Show False

    Set f2 = New UserForm1
    f1.Label1.Caption "I am Form f2"
    f2.Show False
End Sub
```

The code behind of the form simply writes the Caption of a label to the immediate window:

```
Public Sub TestSub()
    Debug.Print "Test: ", Me.Label1.Caption
End Sub
```

Now if you call `UserForm1.TestSub`, what would you expect to see in the immediate window? Answer: Neither *"I am Form1"* nor *"I am Form2"*. VBA would still create the default instance. Instead, you could call the routine by using the object variable, eg with `f1.TestSub` or `f2.TestSub`.

```
Sub TestForms()
    createForms
    
    Call UserForm1.TestSub
    Call f1.TestSub
    Call f2.TestSub
End Sub
```

Will show in the immediate window

```
Test: Label1
Test: I am Form 1
Test: I am Form 2
```

**tl;dr**: Forms a classes and you need to create an object of a class before you can call a method of that class. You need to specify the object if you want to call a method of it.

Comment: If I am creating my form in the editor rather than programmatically, is there a way to convert / create the object later so that I can call subs on it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. "Creating" doesn't mean layout, it means you create an instance of a class (in VBA using the `new` statement) so that you can use it. If you never used `new` to create a form object, you likely use the default instance that is created automatically with VBA. As written, use `Call UserForm1.TestSub` (of course change form and sub name).